# Active Directory multi-site login restrictions: OU or multi-domain?

Tags: active-directory

I'm planning an Active Directory structure from scratch, for a multi-site organization. 
A fundamental point is that a user belonging to site A, if she/he gets to site B, **can't login at all**.

At the same time, while most users' workplace is determined and fixed, a small number of users need to login at multiple site (2-4, but not at every site).

Question: reading docs I can't understand clearly if just one domain with many OU could enforce this behaviour, or I necessarily need multiple subdomains instead.

Any help or hint would be appreciated, many thanks for your time, BR,
Ted

Comment: Better suited for serverfault.com or superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one with one domain and then set up specific groups that you add people too.

That way you could make it so that admin can login across all sites with no problems etc. But users can be in specific site groups that only have access to their site.

Subdomains are ok, but they can get a bit messy in my opinion.

I guess there is no right or wrong answer, its just how you want to organise it and how much time you want to spend maintaining the AD.